# how to calculate range between the dataframe values using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe there is a column of requirement and results. So my target is to get a logic so that i can campare the range given in the requirement and compare it with result and say if its "OK" or "Not OK".

This is my excel screenshot.

[image]

This is just a small screenshot of the excel.

So, if the value is in the range then results column will show as "**OK**" and if the value is not in the range it will show "**NOT OK**"

Is there anyway i can get this thing done by using pandas in python ? 
Please help! 
Ask me if the question is not clear.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate

df = pd.read_csv('Form3.tsv',delimiter='\t')

df = df.loc[df['level'] == 5]
df = df.dropna(subset=['text'])
df = df.loc[df['top'] > 500]
df = df.loc[df['conf'] != 0]
df = df[df['text'].notnull()]
df = df[df['text'] != ' ']
column_separator = 0

distinct_pages = df.page_num.unique()
#print("Distinct pages in file are ",distinct_pages)
df.sort_values(['page_num','line_num','word_num'])
all_rows = []

for each_page in distinct_pages:
    df_each_page = df.loc[df['page_num'] == each_page]
    #print(df_each_page)
    char_num = []
    line_num = []
    ref_loc = []
    charateristic_designator = []
    results = []
    requirement_for_each_line = []
    each_row = []
    current_line_left = 0
    previous_line_left = 1000
    previous_line_width = 1000
    previous_line_number = 1
    line_flag = False
    result_flag = False
    requirement = []
    resultText = ''
    char_num_text = ''
    ref_loc_text = ''
    charateristic_designator_text = ''
    for index, row in df_each_page.iterrows():
        column_separator = 0
        word_num = row['word_num']
        text = row['text']
        Minor_flag = False
        requirement_flag = False
        current_line_number = row['line_num']
        if current_line_number == previous_line_number:
            line_flag = False
        if current_line_number != previous_line_number:
            line_flag = True
            previous_line_number = current_line_number
        current_line_left = row['left']
        column_separator = current_line_left - previous_line_left - previous_line_width
        previous_line_left = current_line_left
        previous_line_width = row['width']
        if (len(results) and column_separator == 6) and 1250 > current_line_left > 1100:
            result_flag = True
        if line_flag is True:
            result_flag = False
        if len(requirement) and word_num in (1,2,3) and text != 'Note' and 800 > current_line_left > 500 and column_separator < 0:
            requirement_flag = True
        if len(requirement) and line_flag is True and (word_num == 1 or (word_num == 2 and column_separator < 0) or (word_num == 4 and column_separator > 300))and requirement_flag is False and result_flag is False and char_num_text != '' and ref_loc_text != '' and charateristic_designator_text != '':
            each_row.append(char_num_text)
            char_num_text = ''
            each_row.append(ref_loc_text)
            ref_loc_text = ''
            each_row.append(charateristic_designator_text)
            charateristic_designator_text = ''
            each_row.append(' '.join(list(dict.fromkeys(requirement))))
            each_row.append(' '.join(results))
            all_rows.append(each_row)
            each_row = []
            requirement_for_each_line.append(requirement)
            requirement = []
            results = []
        if column_separator < 0 and 100 > current_line_left > 70:
            line_num.append(current_line_number)
            char_num.append(text)
            char_num_text = text
        if 210 > current_line_left >= 190:
            ref_loc.append(text)
            ref_loc_text = text
        if 380 > current_line_left > 370 and len(text) == 5:
            charateristic_designator.append(text)
            Minor_flag = True
            charateristic_designator_text = text
        if Minor_flag == False and charateristic_designator_text == '':
            charateristic_designator.append('Minor')
            charateristic_designator_text = 'Minor'
        if  1090 > current_line_left >= 500:# and 98 > column_separator > 0:
            requirement.append(text)
        if 1250 > current_line_left > 1100:# and column_separator > 100:
            results.append(text)
            resultText = text
            result_flag = False
table = tabulate(all_rows, headers=["5. Char No", "6. Reference", "7. Characteristic", "8. Requirement", "9.Results"])
print(table)


headers=["5. Char No", "6. Reference Location", "7. Characteristic Recoginition", "8. Requirement", "9.Results"]
with open('test_file.csv', 'w', newline = '') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    [writer.writerow(r) for r in all_rows]
```

The code is quite complicated because if have basically extracted text from a tesseract thats why its complicated, but the output which i am getting is a huge table, the requirement column also consist of text's but i am concerned only if there is a digit condition. As you can see in the end of the code i have printed my output in a .csv excel file, now on top of the i need to get a logic of getting the range thing in the picture.

Comment: Please share code how you created dataframe. instead of screenshots.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the question, the code is quite dirty and complicated but my target is clear wherever  in requirement column the numeric value is there it checks its range and see if in the results column it is in the same range or not. 
Let me know if you want the tesseract .csv file also. @Mudits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '8. Requirement': ['.685-.695', '.340-.350', '.737-.740', 'foo', '42'],
    '9.Results': [.68, .345, '.739', '.68', 'bar']
})
# or df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep='\t')

df = df.join(df['8. Requirement'].str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)-(\d*\.?\d+)').rename(columns={0:'min', 1:'max'}))
df['OK'] = pd.to_numeric(df['9.Results'], errors='coerce').between(df['min'].astype(float), df['max'].astype(float))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  8. Requirement 9.Results   min   max     OK
0      .685-.695      0.68  .685  .695  False
1      .340-.350     0.345  .340  .350   True
2      .737-.740      .739  .737  .740   True
3            foo       .68   NaN   NaN  False
4             42       bar   NaN   NaN  False
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189627/discussion-on-answer-by-perl-how-to-calculate-range-between-the-dataframe-values).

Answer (score 1):

another solution:

```
data = """
9.results,8. Requirement
.68,.13-.70
.34,.45-.939
.74,.45-.987
.68,.13-.67
.34,.25-.939
.74,.95-.987
   """
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep=',')

df[['low', 'high']] = df['8. Requirement'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df['Status'] = df['9.results'].between(df['low'].astype(float), df['high'].astype(float))
df.drop(['low','high'], axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df)

   9.results 8. Requirement  Status
0     0.68     .13-.70    True
1     0.34    .45-.939   False
2     0.74    .45-.987    True
3     0.68     .13-.67   False
4     0.34    .25-.939    True
5     0.74    .95-.987   False
```

the syntax for a file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv',sep='\t')#  \t if your delimiter is tab
```

Comment: can you edit and tell me how to do it if my csv file name is `test_file.csv` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I am not using the same csv file again to calculate the range, i  have created my a new csv for that i.e. `test_file.csv`. Also like you have given data =" " that data is in this `test_file.csv`. Now can you edit the answer and tell me how i do it ? 
Thanks!

Comment: you have one file for result and one file for requirement?

Comment: i dont understand what you want.. your inital file is csv or excel? you want to create a new csv file?  pd.read_csv('test1.csv',sep='\t') read a csv file with tab as delimiter and create dataframe, the name of column are the same than the first row with header (so 'requirement' in my sample becomes '8. requirement'...)

Comment: If you notice in the end of my code i am printing my output into a new .csv file.
I am using that .csv file and then in that csv file i am comparing my ranges of requirement column and results column. 
The table which you see in the question comes after i run this code, this table is directly copied in a new csv file and then i am using that csv file.

Comment: Hello Sir, its working for me thank you so much! 
Can you help me with one more thing ? Lets say that in requirement column there is text also, but i want my code to just work wherever the range comes. is that possible ? @frenchy

Comment: Basically i want the logic just to focus on the digits and not be concerned about the text.. @frenchy
Thanks!

Comment: you could say that in your initial question , and i have answered followings your inital hypotheses..now you change the question its not good to read the post..i suggest you to close the post , give a note (even its not mine) and repost precisely your problem,

Answer (score 1):

This is one type os solution hope its answers your question. I split the range column into two for easier calculations.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[float(0.685),float(0.695),float(0.68)],[float(0.340),float(0.350),float(0.345)],[float(0.737),float(0.740),float(0.736)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Requirement1','Requirement2','Results'])
print(df)

   Requirement1  Requirement2  Results
0         0.685         0.695    0.680
1         0.340         0.350    0.345
2         0.737         0.740    0.736

### If between the range
f = df['Results'].between(df['Requirement1'], df['Requirement2'], inclusive=False)
df.insert(3,'Status',f)

   Requirement1  Requirement2  Results  Status
0         0.685         0.695    0.680   False
1         0.340         0.350    0.345    True
2         0.737         0.740    0.736   False

### Changing Bool into custom text 
mask = df.applymap(type) != bool 
d = {True: 'OK', False: 'Not OK'}
df = df.where(mask, df.replace(d))
list_col=['Results']
r = df.drop(list_col,axis=1)
r
r.to_csv(filename,mode = 'w', index=False)

    Requirement1  Requirement2  Status
0         0.685         0.695  Not OK
1         0.340         0.350      OK
2         0.737         0.740  Not OK
```